# Attaching to processes in C

Tags: c, linux

I am implementing a netcat clone and currently need a way to run command-line programs over the network.

My solution so far is to execute a process and use pipes for STDIN and STDOUT, then forward the data back and forth over TCP.

The problem is, I feel like this is a round-about way of doing things. When I run bash, the prompt doesn't show up, and I am unable to use ncurses programs, like Vi.

Is there an easier way to control the input and see the output of a program in C, or are pipes my best bet?

Here a portion of my code (click on it, it's very intuitive):

http://pastebin.com/MjyxFkdu

I am using C with GNU/Linux.

Comment: What will your solution offer that `ssh` doesn't?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? You want to want send the commands from your netcat clone, but you want it to return inmedialy so you can use the console again?

Comment: duskwuff was correct, I should have used telnetd as an example. It looks like a pty is what I am looking for. It seems like I can only create one using syscalls.

Comment: Regarding your comment Brian Cain, I am doing this as a way of forcing myself to learn, not because I am displeased with SSH.  Actually, I am very pleased with SSH. :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct terminal behavior can't be obtained using pipes -- you will need to use a [PTY (pseudoterminal)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal) to get the right results.

Note that what you're trying to write here is essentially `telnetd`...