# How to use pseudo-terminals in Linux with C?

Tags: c, linux, pty

I'm trying to figure out how to use pseudo-terminal's in linux, essentially I want to create a telnetd clone, something I mentioned [in an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283524/attaching-to-processes-in-c).

I understand the concept of master and slave terminal, and I have a basic grasp on how to use syscalls in C.

My question concerns the next step after opening a slave / master file descriptor. How to I launch getty in the slave? Are there any *good* resources on the net for using the forkpty(), openpty(),or another API?

Some examples in C would help. [This was a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476354/how-do-nix-pseudo-terminals-work-whats-the-master-slave-channel), but no one really provided any examples.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, 2nd Edition](http://www.apuebook.com/index.html) has a superb chapter on the pseudo-terminal layer available in Linux. The best part is the [source code](http://www.apuebook.com/src.2e.tar.gz) which contains a `pty` driver and very clearly demonstrates how to use the `pty` interfaces. (The `pty` program it builds is useful in its own right if you want to drive a terminal-only program programmatically but don't wish to use `expect(1)`.)

Comment: @JérémyPouyet, thanks for the notice; I've fixed the link to point to the second edition code (which is the code I'm familiar with) -- perhaps the third edition would be the better choice, but I haven't personally read that code yet. Some day. :)

Comment: @CiroSantilli巴拿馬文件六四事件法轮功, sorry, I cannot find a license. Neither the second edition tarball nor the third edition tarball specify a license, the FAQs on the website do not specify a license. There is a `DISCLAIMER` file in the top level of the tarball which suggests it's intended to be used and useful but disclaims all liability for all consequences.

Comment: Yeah, that's about what I've found too. Maybe I'll email the author, if open that has to go to GitHub :-)

Comment: kerrisk's linux programming interface also has a chapter on it: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-programming-interface-kerrisk/tree/c02ede2d146e0529f3b01d513a4d3894a1761f08/pty

Answer (score 5):

## include

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <fcntl.h>

#define _XOPEN_SOURCE

#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
char *slavename;
int masterfd;
masterfd = open("/dev/ptmx", O_RDWR);
grantpt(masterfd);
unlockpt(masterfd);
slavename = ptsname(masterfd);
...
}
```

I posted simple example of demonstrating pseudo terminal master slave concept. please go through this link to get clear understanding of terminals in Linux
**http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/**

Comment: This is the simple straightforward answer. It's documented here: http://linux.die.net/man/4/ptmx

Answer (score 0):

You don't *lauch a getty* for ptys. The getty is only the "listener" part of the process. For hardwired terminals, each individual terminal-device is "listening" constantly. For telnet, the daemon does the listening part(on a socket), and handles connection request by *creating* a pty pair, and fork()ing / exec()ing. 
And indeed: APUE handles ptys very well.