# Ncurses programs in pseudo-terminals

Tags: c, linux

In my continuing attempt to understand how pseudo-terminals work, I have written a small program to try to run bash.

The problem is, my line-breaking seems to be off. (The shell prompt only appears AFTER I press enter.)

Furthermore, I still cannot properly use ncurses programs, like vi. Can anyone tell me how to setup the pseudo-terminal for this?

[My badly written program can be found here, I encourage you to compile it](http://pastebin.com/xaj2cSsv). The operating system is GNU/Linux, thanks.

EDIT: Compile like this: gcc program.c -lutil -o program

EDIT AGAIN: It looks like the issue with weird spacing was due to using printf(), still doesn't fix the issue with ncurses programs though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using pseudo-terminals in linux with C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374000/using-pseudo-terminals-in-linux-with-c)

Comment: If you haven't already, sign up for a free github/bitbucket account. Keep your source code in the repository, and get free sharing, diff, history and so on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several issues in your program. Some are relatively easy to fix - others not so much:

1. [`forkpty()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/forkpty) and its friends come from BSD and *are not POSIX compatible*. They should be avoided for new programs. From the [`pty(7) manual page`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pty):

   > Historically, two pseudoterminal APIs have evolved: BSD and System V. SUSv1 standardized a pseudoterminal API based on the System V API, and this API should be employed in all new programs that use pseudoterminals.

   You should be using [`posix_openpt()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_openpt) instead. This issue is probably not critical, but you should be aware of it.
2. You are mixing calls to raw system calls ([`read()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read), [`write()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write)) and file-stream ([`printf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf), [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)) functions. This is a very good way to confuse yourself. In general you should choose *one* approach and stick with it. In this case, it's probably best to use the low-level system calls ([`read()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read), [`write()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write)) to avoid any issues that would arise from the presence of the I/O buffers that the C library functions use.
3. You are assuming a line-based paradigm for your terminals, by using [`printf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) and [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets). This is not always true, especially when dealing with interactive programs like `vim`.
4. You are assuming a C-style single-byte null-terminated string paradigm. Terminals normally deal with characters and bytes - not strings. And while most character set encodings avoid using a zero byte, *not all do so*.
5. As a result of (2), (3) and (4) above, you are not using [`read()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) and [`write()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) correctly. You should be using their return values to determine how many bytes they processed, not string-based functions like [`strlen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen).
6. This is the issue that, in my opinion, will be most difficult to solve: You are implicitly assuming that:

   - *The terminal (or its driver) is stateless:* It is not. Period. There are at least two stateful controls that I suspect are the cause of ncurses-based programs not working correctly: The [line mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_%28telecommunication%29#Modes) and the [local echo control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_%28computing%29) of the terminal. At least these have to match between the parent/master and the slave terminal in order to avoid various strange artifacts.
   - *The control-interface of a terminal can be passed-through just by passing the bytes back and forth:* It is not always so. Modern virtual terminals allow for a degree of out-of-band control via [`ioctl()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ioctl) calls, as described for Linux [here](http://linux.die.net/man/4/tty_ioctl).

   The simplest way to deal with this issue is probably to set the parent terminal to raw mode and let the slave pseudo-terminal driver deal with the awkward details.

You may want to have a look at [this program](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/pty/script.c.html) which seems to work fine. It comes from the book [The Linux Programming Interface](http://www.man7.org/tlpi/) and the full source code is [here](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/index.html). *Disclaimer: I have not read the book, nor am I promoting it - I just found the program using Google.*

Comment: TLPI is written by Michael Kerrisk, who is doing an outstanding job maintaining the Linux manpages.