# Python curses with scrolling terminal

Tags: python, curses, python-curses

I want to build an app on my raspberry pi using Python that uses a curses-style display over part of the screen and keeping the terminal visible (whilst printing scrolling status messages in it) over the rest of the screen. I also want to be able to take user input from the terminal prompt. Is this possible and how would I go about implementing this?

Comment: You could start here: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/curses.html

Comment: Here is what looks to be a solution using shell programming: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25712471/3901060