# Is it possible to override SSH expecting password input from /dev/tty in C

Tags: c, ssh, solaris

I am developing a piece of software in C that needs to SSH to another machine and run commands as root.

Something that looks like this:

```
char* GetPasswd(void);

void run(char* apnSshCommand)
{
   FILE* lphSshFD = popen(apnSshCommand,"w");
   fprintf(lphSshFD,GetPasswd());
   fflush(lphSshFD);
   fprintf(lphSshFD,"#Command to run in shell");
   fflush(lphSshFD);
}
```

GetPasswd() would be a callback to a gui where the user has typed in the password

I know that the above code is not possible since SSH looks to it's own /dev/tty to provide the password for authentication.

I have read posts such as [this](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22014012/popen-ssh-w-dev-tty.html) that teases an answer using ioctl() and fcntl() but does not provide one. Along with [this](https://andre.frimberger.de/index.php/linux/reading-ssh-password-from-stdin-the-openssh-5-6p1-compatible-way/) that shows it is possible from the command line however I have not been able to translate it.

Using expect is **NOT** an option

Using SSH keys are **NOT** an option

The SSH C library is **NOT** an option

Using sshpass is **NOT** an option

Without these, the only thing that I can think of is starting a new child process and redirect/close file descriptors to control what ssh has access to.

EDIT: These restrictions come from the fact that the system I am working on is extremely old and does not contain tools such as expect, sshpass and the SSH C library as well as being subject to multiple restrictions in regards to when sshkeys can be used

Comment: `fprintf(lphSshFD,GetPasswd());` looks wrong. Where is the format string argument to `fprintf()`?

Comment: How about using SSH public keys?

Comment: `lpSshFD` looks wrong, are you programming Windows API?

Comment: You can run `ssh` in a child process and connect to it using a pseudo-tty.

Comment: What's `sshpass` mentioned as a non-option? is that supposed to be `SSH_ASKPASS`?

Comment: You could allocate a pty, launch ssh with the pty as its input, and respond to the password prompt from ssh. You'd be reimplementing expect or sshpass.

Comment: @Barmar, running ssh in a child process and connecting to it using a pseudo-tty sounds like a way forward, but I am unsure of how to do that.

Comment: @dhke sshpass is a utility that can be used to pass the password to ssh in plaintext but it is unavailable to me

Comment: @Kenster Can you provide a link to some place that shows me how to do this

Comment: Search for the sshpass source code.

Comment: And the password MUST be asked before the connection is made? Because otherwise, providing your own `SSH_ASKPASS` agent is probably the simplest approach.

Comment: Why not use something like `libssh` directly instead of using a subprocess?

Comment: @chepner Question says "The SSH C library is NOT an option"

Comment: Where are all these restrictions coming from? These are all the usual methods to use SSH from a program, you're deliberately excluding them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374000/how-to-use-pseudo-terminals-in-linux-with-c http://rachid.koucha.free.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html

Comment: *subject to multiple restrictions in regards to when sshkeys can be used* In other words, the people who wrote the restrictions don't understand security.  They're forcing you to kludge up a solution for an already-solved problem, and your solution likely requires leaving the other account password available on disk.  And that appears to be the other *root* password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shell script to automate SSH login using password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43526330/shell-script-to-automate-ssh-login-using-password)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution by looking at the source code for sshpass which I found [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Create a script called `pwd.sh` that emits the password:

```
 #!/bin/bash                                                                                                                  
 echo -n mypassword
```

Run ssh in a new session like this:

```
 SSH_ASKPASS=/path/to/pwd.sh DISPLAY= setsid -w ssh root@192.168.1.10 <command>
```

The effect of `setsid` is to run `ssh` detached from the controlling terminal, which is what is needed for it to respect SSH_ASKPASS.

I haven't tried, but I would expect to be able to run this command from C using `system()`.

For the record, I tested this with OpenSSH_7.2p2 on Ubuntu.

Comment: It's available for OpenSolaris, so that problem might not be insurmountable. If it is, it shouldn't be difficult to compile the  ~40 lines of C that the `setsid` implementation requires. Or just use it as the basis for some other implementation of a wrapper for `ssh`. Or perhaps just cook up a similar effect using some combination of `nohup`, `&`, and redirection.